# How to find false option related to x mod two integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying questions of masters of mathematics exam of my Institute and I was unable to solve this particular problem.

Please note that exam is choosing single correct option from 4 MCQ's and so we can devote relatively  less time to a question than subjective exam.

Its image:

[image]

Can anyone please tell how to solve this question using some short method.

I am unable to think how to find correct option.

Comment: For an example of an "impossible" pair of congruences, look at something like $n\equiv 5 \pmod {12}$ and $n\equiv 1\pmod 3$.  Try to use the same principle with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem. While I wouldn't know the prime divisors of $6789$, I do know the prime divisors of $1000$: $5$ and $2$. Clearly, 6789 is not divisible by either $5$ or $2$, so by the Chinese remainder theorem, we are guaranteed a solution. Thus, we can eliminate choices (1) and (2).

As for the other two choices, we look at smaller divisors. So if $x\equiv 32 \pmod{1000}$, then x must be divisible by $4$. Therefore, we can look at the other two choices to see which of those would not result in divisibility by $4$.

This is a general procedure for solving the problem, and some may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x\equiv 32\pmod{1000}$ implies $x\equiv 0\pmod 4$, but $x\equiv 54\pmod{9876}$  implies $x\equiv 2\pmod 4$.

Comment: 9876 is completely divisible by 4.

Comment: This is true. Therefore, $x\equiv 54\pmod {9876}$ implies $\equiv 54\equiv 2\pmod 4$